# Displaying data into angular 2 datatable

Tags: php, angularjs

I have been able to fetch data from my database which only shows up in the console of my browser. What i specifically want to do is, display those data fetched into my angular 2 table created. I have been at this for quite a while. kindly help. below is my code.

**My http service**

```
 import {Response, Http} from '@angular/http';
 import {DataListModule} from 'primeng/primeng';

 @Injectable()    
 export class HttpService {

      constructor(private http:Http) {}

      getData() {
           //using get request
           return this.http.get('example.com')
                .map((response: Response) => response.json())    
      }
 }
```

**My component**

```
 import {Component, OnInit} from '@angular/core';
 import {HttpService} from "./Client_Service";
 import {Response} from '@angular/http';

 @Component({
      selector: 'client',
      templateUrl:'client_table.html',
      providers:[HttpService]
 })    
 export class GameComponent {

      Games: [{
           EAsports: string,
           Konami: string,
           Country:string,
           BestGame: string,
      }];

      constructor(private httpService: HttpService){
           this.Games = [{    
                EAsports: " FIFA",
                Konami: "PES",
                Country:"CHINA",
                BestGame: "FIFA 17"
           }]
      }

      ngOnInit() {

           this.httpService.getData()
                .subscribe((data: any) => {
                     console.log(data.json())
                     this.Games = data;
                })    
      }
 }
```

**My Table**

```
 <tr>
    <th>#</th>
    <th>FIFA 17</th>
    <th>PES 17</th>
    <th>ORIGIN</th>
    <th>CALL OF DUTY</th>
 </tr>

 <tr *ngFor="let game of Games; let i = index">
      <td>{{i + 1}}</td>
      <td><a href="#" >{{game.EAsports}}</a></td>
      <td>{{game.Konami}}</td>
      <td>{{game.Country}}</td>
      <td>{{game.BestGame}}</td>
  </tr>
```

Comment: What's problem you have?

Comment: @AvneshShakya, I want the data in my database to show up in the table i created.  when i check the console of my browser, i see the data has been fetched but it doesnt appear in my table created

Comment: try to bind: `{{Games}}` in template and see how's coming?

Comment: @AvneshShakya,  i am not really clear of what you saying

Comment: I mean in `client_table.html` file where `table` html is there.

Comment: @AvneshShakya, after binding, i see this under each column " [object Object]"

Comment: What does the JSON response look like?

Comment: Please check response and template, are they same?

Comment: @SteveG. it looks like this in my console  EAsports: " FIFA",
                Konami: "PES",
                Country:"CHINA",
                BestGame: "FIFA 17"

Comment: @AvneshShakya, i just checked again and it is the same please

Comment: Hard to tell from what you provided. Is that an array with one object or just an object?

Comment: @SteveG.    Array [ Object, Object, Object, Object, Object, Object, Object ] .That is what happens in the console. An array of objects